# Aperture and field of view - percepted by eye vs camera

Tags: lens, aperture, optics, field-of-view, eyes

I very well informed and I know about how aperture works and why is it not restricting field of view, but I somehow cannot get around the following:

Aperture doesn't restrict field of view for the camera, but when I take the lens off camera and I look throught it with my own eyes, it definitelly restricts the area that I can see through the lens.

So why is that? Even though it seems quite intuitive :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of differences in how your eyes and your camera work.

In your camera, the rear element of the lens is the final optical element before the image is formed.  The aperture iris is placed at or near the point of "maximum out-of-focusness" (the optical center of the lens) so that the shadow of the iris is spread evenly over the entire image.

By looking through the lens with your eyes, you place an additional active element in the system: the lens of your eye.  This changes things dramatically, and the aperture iris is now nowhere near the optimal point, thus the restriction in field of view.  You can see a similar effect sometimes in very old photographs, where aperture control was done using a device in front of the lens rather than integrated into it, causing the corners of the image to be darkened.